# WooCommerce: Add-on option label doesn't take negative price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I'm using WooCommerce v. 2.1.7. I'm also using the following skinning plugin, which made my skinning customizations easier:
http://themeforest.net/item/mommerce-modern-multipurpose-woocommerce-theme/6727886

I have a product page that looks something like this:

[image]

I'm trying to add a price to "Try on" a dress for less than the 7-day rental price ($910). It's set up like the following in the WooCommerce backend:

[image]

When I try to select "New Option" and add a -875 or any negative number, WooCommerce screams at me. How can I get this to accept a negative value?

Ideas I thought of:

1. Where do I find, and remove, the validator that makes WooCommerce scream at me for entering a negative value?
2. Where exactly do I find the code in this system to hard code the try-on price value?

Comment: Are you saying that you are going to pay the customer to try on a dress? If the 7-day option is $910 and the "try on" is less than just make that option less..ex: $800. Or please explain further why that won't work, because right now I don't understand negative pricing at all.

Comment: @helgatheviking The customer is going to pay us to try on a dress. $910 is the cost to rent the dress for 7 days and $1730 (+$820) is the cost to rent the dress for 14 days. 

I'm trying to implement a low-cost way ($20-$40) for customers to try on the dress by purchasing it via a try-on radio button option (just like you see for the 7day and 14-day rental options).

The problem is that Product Data options does not let me subtract the price difference between the 7-day rental price and the try-on rental price to even create the try-on price because it doesn't accept negative values.

Comment: Ok, but why do you need to subtract the price at all? Why can't you create a "try on" option and set the price to $20?

Comment: Because the logic for these options doesn't seem to work like that. The logic in these options is it adds the option price to the "Rental Price" in the pink box. 

Also, I, of course, can't change the rental price to the "try-on" price of $20 because that's not the rental price.

Comment: I think your question concerned the Add-Ons plugin more than it does that themeforest theme. Anyway, have you considered making the rental period a variation attribute? I see you already have size, so I presume the product is already a variable product. Even if we can figure out how to get past allowing the negative price input, I think you're going to run into other problems down the line.